# how to get child category title and image

Tags: categories

In my theme there have category and child categories, for categories image i used **Categories Images**

So now my category structure like bellow

**Photos**

1. Sub Category 1
2. Sub Category 2
3. Sub Category 3

Now I create custom category page for photos `category-photos.php` I want show here all child category title with post count and category image with link to page.

I am tried many way but not properly success yet, i Will keep update here. In the meantime if you guys can help it would be greate

For getting image from Categories Images doc is here 
 `http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/`

Bellow is my code. Here I am not getting post country and child category. current all category coming

```
    <ul>
    <?php 
    foreach (get_categories() as $cat) : ?>
    <li>
    <?php z_taxonomy_image($cat->term_id); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>">
<?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?><span>post count number here</span></a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```